# Bash's wait command does not return 0 if a child exits non-zero

Tags: bash

It seems that bash's `wait` doesn't honor `set -e` as I would expect. Or it somehow loses track of the child process exiting with an error. Consider the example.

```
set -e # exit immediately on error

function child()
{
    if [ $1 -eq 3 ]; then
        echo "child $1 performing error"
        # exit 1 ## I also tried this
        false
    else
        echo "child $1 performing successful"
        true
    fi
    echo "child $1 exiting normally"
}

# parent
child 1 & # succeeds
child 2 & # fails
child 3 & # succeeds
wait # why doesn't wait indicate an error?
echo "Launch nukes!" # don't want this to execute if a child failed
```

I want the `set -e` semantics, but `wait` doesn't seem to honor them.
A parent launches three children.  One of them chokes and exits with an error (honoring the `set -e`).  The problem is that the parent process plunders on as if nothing bad happened silently. I.e. I want to propagate the error.

Is there a way to enable this behavior? I.e. have wait return non-zero if any child exits non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Man page](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html), that's what should happen (emphasis mine):

> If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited
>   for, and **the return status is zero**.

You want the second form where you specify `wait {pid1} {pid2} {...}` and get back the right error code.

Comment: Hm for the form with pid my bash manpage states (emphasis mine) "Otherwise, the return status is  the exit status of the **last process** or job waited for." so still no guarantee to get any non-zero status, or do I see it wrong? - except if you wait on them one-by-one

Comment: @StefanHegny You're right, `wait pid1 pid2` only returns the status of pid2

Comment: You need `wait -n` (in `bash` 4.3 or later) to get the exit status for a single arbitrary child. (You won't know *which* child exited, though.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `bash` 4.3, you can use `wait -n` in a loop to wait for each child in turn. You won't know *which* child failed, but whenever one does fail, the exit status of `wait` will be non-zero.

```
child 1 & # succeeds
child 2 & # fails
child 3 & # succeeds
for i in 1 2 3; do
    wait -n
done
```

Comment: what if child3 terminates before child1 ?